# What is this (potentially malicious) Java code trying to do?

Tags: java, buffer-overflow

Over on Reddit, a user claimed they'd found 'a potential bug in Java', and provided the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Java_bug_demonstration{
    public static void main(String[]str_data){
        ArrayList<Short>[]s_al_arr=new ArrayList[683];
        short s0=-1,s1=0;
        while(s1<2266){
            short s2=Short.parseShort("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".substring(s1++,++s1),36);
            if(s2>=648){s_al_arr[++s0]=new ArrayList<Short>();}
            if(s2!=648){
                s_al_arr[s0].add((short)(s2%648));
                s_al_arr[s2%648].add(s0);}}
        LinkedList<Short>q=new LinkedList<Short>();
        short[] ERROROUS_ARR=new short[s_al_arr.length];
        boolean[] b_arr=new boolean[s_al_arr.length];
        for(short s2=0;s2<s_al_arr.length;s2+=1){
            for(int i0=0;i0<ERROROUS_ARR.length;i0+=1){
                b_arr[i0]=false;
                ERROROUS_ARR[i0]=-1;
                if(ERROROUS_ARR[i0]!=-1){System.out.println("ERROROUS_ARR[i0] is always -1 here. So this line is not printed.");}}
            for(int i0=0;i0<ERROROUS_ARR.length;i0+=1){
                if(ERROROUS_ARR[i0]==0){
                    System.out.println("BUG!!!: ERROROUS_ARR:"+Arrays.toString(ERROROUS_ARR));
                    System.exit(1);}}
            b_arr[s2]=true;
            q.add(s2);
            while(!q.isEmpty()){
                short i1=q.remove();
                for(int i0=0;i0<s_al_arr[i1].size();i0+=1){
                    short s3=s_al_arr[i1].get(i0);
                    if(!b_arr[s3]){
                        b_arr[s3]=true;
                        ERROROUS_ARR[s3]=i1;
                        q.add(s3);}}
                if(i1>s2){while(i1!=-1){i1=ERROROUS_ARR[i1];}}//bug occurs, but with smaller probability if this line is removed.
                ERROROUS_ARR[s2]=-1;/*bug occurs, but with smaller probability if this statement is removed.*/}}
        System.exit(0);}}
```

In the above, the variable `s2` is assigned the result of an attempt to parse an extremely long string of data, which looks distinctly 'buffer-overflowy' to me.

Can anyone with Java experience elaborate on what's going on?

Comment: If some bug is occurring with some probability then I would assume it's because of a race condition within the JVM. I ran the code in an online Java parser, but I haven't seen any indications that the bug occurred. Did you verify that certain versions of Java will end up printing the `BUG!!!` line?

Comment: I tried running it online, but the parser complained about unsafe code. The user didn't specify a Java version. Original thread here, if you're interested: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/nh4cge/have_i_found_bug_in_java/

Comment: What does it have to do with information security? This question is off topic here.

Comment: This is a programming question. We do not analyse random code here. Else we'd be flooded with random code.

Comment: Agreed: whoever attempted this migration definitely does not understand Stack Overflow very well.

Answer (score 1):

That very long string ... you're taking the substring from index `s1++` to `++s1` (which will be 2 chars from `s1` to `s1+2`. Then you're parsing it as an integer using base 36. Not really sure why you'd want to do that, but everything is properly bounded, so it does not look like any type of overflow to me.

Comment: I could see that much was going on. I was suspicious of the length of the string, the repeating characters at the start (like NOPs in overflows), and the advice from the original poster (who joined Reddit an hour ago) that it would only work if run from the terminal, and not if stepped through in an IDE. It screamed scam to me.

Comment: I'm not saying that the code is not malicious. It's definitely written to be intentionally hard to read so I have no idea what it's actually doing, I'm just responding to your question about whether the long string is a buffer overflow.